# Are the terms 'clan' and 'tribe' common in mathematics?

Tags: measure-theory, vector-spaces, terminology

In the book *'Vector Measures'* by Dinculeanu,  he starts the discussion by talking about "classes of sets", and introduces two pieces of terminology I've never seen before, and can't find any evidence of being used elsewhere.

> A nonvoid class $\mathcal{C}$ of subsets of T is called a *clan* if
>
> - $A-B\in\mathcal{C}$, for $A,B\in \mathcal{C}$
> - $A\cup B\in \mathcal{C}$, for $A,B\in \mathcal{C}$

And

> A nonvoid class $\mathcal{T}$ of subsets of T is called a *tribe* if
>
> - $A-B\in\mathcal{C}$, for $A,B\in \mathcal{C}$
> - $\cup^\infty_{i=1}A_i\in\mathcal{T}$ for every sequence $(A_i)$ of sets of $\mathcal{T}$

Now he does make a footnote that "clan" is also called a "ring, by Halmos", and that "tribe" is called (also by Halmos) a "$\sigma$-ring". But I'm curious, why these new, odd terms? And are they used elsewhere commonly at all?

Sorry, btw, of my latex is messed up. I'm on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for editing, @Zev. I couldn't get that list to format correctly on mobile.

Comment: They are not new terms. They are terms originally used in French. Even today we find some texts in French using those terms, although "ring" and "$\sigma$-ring" have became kind of international standard.

Comment: I know they aren't knew, but I am curious if I ever used them, if I'd be looked at like a crazy person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not new terms. They are terms originally used in French. Even today we find some texts in French using those terms, although "ring" and "$\sigma$-ring" have became kind of international standard.